# Time discrepancies in a form export

Tags: commcare

In my form export, I see three meta data times:
1) started_time
2) completed_time
3) received_on

I understand that 3 is when the form reaches the server, which can be delayed depending on when the device is on a live connection. However, I have two questions:

1) What time zones are each of these three times in?
2) I am seeing an odd discrepancy where the started_time and the completed_time are AFTER the received_on time, and I do not understand how that can happen if we assume the tablet is set to the correct time. Help!

Answer (score 1):

When CommCare HQ processes forms it converts all the dates to UTC which is what you'll see when you do an export.

When displaying dates in a report it will convert the date back to the timezone configured for that user / project.

If the `timeStart` or `timeEnd` dates are after `received_on` then that indicates that the time settings on the mobile device are incorrect.

To view the original date and time that was captured in the form you can view the form XML. This will show the `timeStart` and `timeEnd` values as they were before being converted to UTC. You can view the form XML using the [Submit History report](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Submit+History)

Comment: More info in the user docs: https://wiki.commcarehq.org/display/commcarepublic/Form+Completion+versus+Form+Submission+and+Timezones and https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Time+Zone+Settings